# How to go back in explorer manager?

Tags: directory, shortcuts

I am new in Ubuntu and I do not find how to "go back" at the previus view while I am travelling in the folders.
Is there a keyboard shortcut for this action? (in windows I can use "left arrow" to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top left of the window you can find the button to go back. If you want to do that on the keyboard hold ALT and press left arrow (if you want to go back) or right arrow (if you want to go forward).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whats the Files version you are using. But I do have such option.

[image]

Any way If you want to move with HotKeys then

<kbd>ALt</kbd>+ <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> = Backward

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> = Forward